# Laravel Coversion consulta sql a queryBuilder(Laravel)

Tags: laravel, t-sql, query-builder

translate consult sql to queryBuider.
        SELECT COUNT(attendances.status) 
        FROM lessons
        INNER JOIN attendances
        ON lessons.ID = attendances.lesson_id
        where attendances.status=1 and attendances.student_id=1 and lessons.subject_id=1

Comment: On Stack Overflow, all questions must be in English. Please [edit] your question and translate it to English. Or you could post your question on [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this:

```
DB::table('lessons')
            ->join('attendances', 'lessons.id', '=', 'attendances.lesson_id')
            ->where('attendances.status', '=', 1)
            ->where('attendances.student_id', '=', 1)
            ->where('attendances.subject_id', '=', 1)
            ->count()
            ->get();
```